# Does Windows 10 S installer delete files on other drives?

Tags: windows-10, installer, windows-10s

Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/education/windows/test-windows10s-for-edu) article. Microsoft described how to install Windows 10 in S mode in existing Installation. I also want S mode of Windows, so I also want to do that. Everything is fine, but I am worried that, does the installer delete anything out of C drive? Well I backed up everything of C:, but I have a lot of data in D: so I am worried that if it gets deleted? Have anyone tried this? Did it deleted any other drives?? Thanks!

Comment: [Kept Files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/education/windows/test-windows10s-for-edu#kept-files): Back up all your data before installing Windows 10 in S mode. Only personal files may be kept during installation. Your settings and apps will be deleted. -- With how specific this is you probably want a clean device as it will heavily limit what you can do anyway.

Comment: @Seth So what can I do?

Comment: You could use a VM or backup your stuff before giving it a try

Comment: yes i could Backup, but is over 200GB and all external devices are full. VM isn't working.... @Seth

Comment: You will absolutely be unable to keep your personal files on your system drive if you install Windows in S mode. Backup your files before you attempt those instructions. We won’t be able to restore your files if you ignore this warning

Comment: What about other drives, @Ramhound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own Question.

This is my experience:

- I installed Windows 10 Pro 21H1 in VMWare.
- I downloaded Windows 10 S installer
- It downloaded Win10S

Then it asked "Choose what to keep" and the only option was "Nothing". And there was written "Your apps and settings cannot be kept because Windows is installed in unsupported directory or You are trying to install an older version of windows.". So I just proceeded. Now, its checking and getting updates.

Then it showed:
Installing Windows 10 then "Your pc needs to reboot to continue.." and then "Installing Windows #% complete" After that.. If booted! i setup then, It didn't deleted ANY drives! wow great!

> I will soon edit my post as soon as I catch another information, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All Windows installers only touch the system drive for software installation.

The installers don't touch other disks, unless, for example,
a specialized partition is required for recovery. But even then it will
only reduce the size of some existing partition to create the
new partition, and will not delete existing partitions.

An exception for Windows S might occur when non-Microsoft software
is installed on a non-system disk.
However, according to your link, non-Microsoft apps will simply not work.
The article does not mention the uninstallation of such applications.

Before doing the installation, I suggest taking a disk-image backup
of the current system disk (not only the partition), in case you will find
that Windows 10 S is too limited and wish to return to your previous state.

Comment: _However, according to your link, non-Microsoft apps will simply not work. The article does not mention the uninstallation of such applications._ **Please check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/education/windows/test-windows10s-for-edu#kept-files) section.** ,_I suggest taking a disk-image backup of the current system._ **How?**

Comment: From the link: "Your settings and apps will be deleted" is ambiguous, but I believe it means that they are deleted from Windows but not from the disk. It would surprise me if I'm wrong, but that's why I counsel a disk backup.

Comment: A good and efficient tool for taking disk backups is [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html). You should also [Create Windows PE Bootable Media](https://www.ubackup.com/help/create-bootable-disk.html) and test it to see if it can see both the system disk and the backup file.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: You might check my post.